# mysql configuration for specific user

Tags: linux, mysql, configuration

Is it possible to create different mysql configurations (mysql.cnf files) for specific linux user?

I want to come up with a solution so current user (linux, already authenticated) can have access to mysql by default without having to use -u and -p arguments. Each linux users would already have their mysql user set up with proper permissions on their databases.

Examples of configuration files I would like to set up. By default, the first mysql conf (default.mysql.conf) would be used but if one of the 3 users; root, www-data or bob are logged in, I would like mysql to use the corresponding configuration file. Is it possible to make this work?

default.mysql.conf

```
...
[client]
# nothing, must authenticate with -u and -p arguments
...
```

root.mysql.conf

```
...
[client]
user = mysqlroot
password = AbCdEfG1234pwd
...
```

www-data.mysql.conf

```
...
[client]
user = mysqlwwwdata
password = AbCdEfG1234wwwpwd
...
```

bob.mysql.conf

```
...
[client]
user = mysqlbob
password = AbCdEfG1234bobpwd
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you want to create is `$HOME/.my.cnf`, in each user's home directory, from which the MySQL client will read configuration directives for each corresponding user.

Comment: oh that's as simple as that. Ok thanks But what if I want to execute shell commands from php (which uses a non existent www-data user), how I can create a .my.cnf for www-data

Comment: You don't need any of this for PHP; you would just talk to MySQL directly in the code. You certainly would not call a shell command to run `mysql`.

Comment: I actually want to trigger a shell script from php. In that shell script, I need to perform some manipulations, then execute mysql, then perform other manipulations. I would like to avoid to specify the password within that shell script.

Comment: finally I had the wrong approach. php > shell script > mysql is not a good idea. But /.my.cnf is the thing I was looking for thanks.